# How to use stringr and regexp to remove spaces and digits from end of strings?

Tags: regex, r

I need to write a basic regular expression in `R` that I cannot figure out. What I am trying to do is to remove the number and space from the data, so that "Flagstaff 24" becomes "Flagstaff".

```
library(stringr)

data <- c("Flagstaff 24",  "Los Angeles 23", "Cleveland 29", "Cleveland 29",  "Seattle 22")
```

However as my numbers are either one or two digits I cannot just trim the end. What I have tried are the following expressions that do not work:

```
str_split_fixed(data, ".\\d", 1)
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around these expression structures!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `gsub()` for this. (No need for the `stringr` package.)

```
gsub("\\s*\\d*$", "", data)
[1] "Flagstaff"   "Los Angeles" "Cleveland"   "Cleveland"   "Seattle"
```

Comment: Thank you! Why does this expression ignore the space in Los Angeles? What I was trying to do was just look at the end of the string, but it seems that was not necessary.

Comment: @celenius -- The `$` is an 'anchor' that means "end of the string". So this will only match and replace a sequence of characters that has: (1) zero or more space characters; (b) followed by zero or more digits; (3) followed immediately by the end of the string. The space (and alphabetical characters) in "Los Angeles" don't match as part of that regular expression, so aren't replaced. Make sense?

Comment: ah yes, makes perfect sense. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: or an alternative syntax: `gsub(" [[:digit:]]+$", "", data)`, but yeah, it's the same thing...